# PHP regex replace 'minus'

Tags: php

I am trying to remove the 'minus' from a string, but if there are three in sequence I want to keep one.

For example:

```
today-is---sunny--but-yesterday---it-wasnt
```

Become:

```
today is - sunny but yesterday - it wasnt
```

I was trying to str_replace the - but obviously is removin all of them.

Basicaly I want to remove maximum 2 in sequence.. If there's more keep it.

Comment: Is `foo - bar` a valid input, with spaces around the hyphen? What should happen there? And what about `----`, or even more than four repeated hyphens? Read [ask] and elaborate more about your input.

Comment: So if it's one get rid of it and if it's 3 replace them with `" - "`? What if it's 2 or 4?

Comment: Basicaly I want to remove maximum 2 in sequence.. If there's more keep it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I *think* this handles the cases mentioned by your updates

```
$string = "today-is---sunny--but-yesterday---it-wasnt----nothing-----five";

$newstring = preg_replace("/(\-{1,2})(?!\-)/", " ", $string);
$newstring = preg_replace("/(\-+)/", " $1", $newstring);

echo $newstring;
```

Output is:

> today is - sunny but yesterday - it wasnt -- nothing --- five

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a8895c9aa3f66e9b812219625c9b25ff1c652329)

So it matches 1 or 2 dashes that are *not* followed by a dash and replaces with a space.  In the case of more than 2 consecutive dashes, this means it matches only the last 2 in the consecutive string.  Then we match a group of 1 or more dashes and precede it with a space.

Answer (score 4):

Not smart enough to make it into one regex so here's 2:

```
$string = "today-is---sunny--but-yesterday---it-wasnt";   
$string = preg_replace("/\b-{1,2}\b/", " ", $string);
$string = preg_replace("/\b-{3,}\b/", " - ", $string);
```

[Seems to work](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6a99cb23175792d78d05a6592a57009d9ae7e5a1)

Comment: Woahh exactly the same idea, nice!

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Wow. The same idea at around the same time.

Comment: I wanted it to be dynamic, if there are ---- becomes --, basically i want to remove 2 -- if there's 2 or more.

Comment: @Roots You should update your question with more case scenarios and what you'd like to happen.

Comment: I did. "Basicaly I want to remove maximum 2 in sequence.. If there's more keep it."

Comment: @Roots can you be a bit more specific? What would you do in this case: `The-quick--brown---fox----jumps-----over------the-------lazy--------dog`?

Comment: That would be the string: The quick brown - fox -- jumps --- over ---- the ----- lazy ------ dog

Answer (score 3):

I would do this in 2 steps using regex.

First, replace the minus symbol with a space if there is 1 or 2 surrounded by word boundries.

```
preg_replace("/(\b(-){1,2}\b)/", " ", $string);
```

Pattern ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/r6WU72/1)):

```
word boundry | minus sign (1 or 2) | word boundry
```

Then, replace all instances of 3 or more minus signs with a minus sign surrounded by spaces.

```
preg_replace("/(\b(-){3,}\b)/", " - ", $string);
```

Pattern ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dLrOhi/1)):

```
word boundry | minus sign (3 or more) | word boundry
```

*Note: None of the parenthesis in my example code patterns are required, buet I believe they help readability.*

I personally love the way regex101 lays out exactly what is happening in the top right corner of the website with a given pattern, so if you'd like to learn more about how this (or other regex patterns) work, then regex101 is a wonderful resource.

Answer (score 2):

Solution with a callback:

```
$new = preg_replace_callback(
    '/[-]+/',
    function ($m) {
        return 2 < strlen($m[0])? ' - ' : ' ';
    },
    'today-is---sunny--but-yesterday---it-wasnt'
);
// today is - sunny but yesterday - it wasnt
```

Comment: Basicaly I want to remove maximum 2 in sequence.. If there's more keep it.. Like that, if there are 4 of them, it's not working.

Comment: Modify callback as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in three steps:

- first replace `'/---+/'` by `'@minus@'` (or some other recognisable placeholder)
- then replace all `/[- ]+/` by `' '` (a single blank)
- replace all`'@minus@'` by `' - '`

Comment: if the string is dynamic there's always the risk the placeholder is already in the string or otherwise causes mis-identification `@minus-two` for example.

Comment: The idea is to pick an "impossible string". Something you will never expect in the string intself. Obviously there will never be a hundred percent security for such a string, but in a general case it is doable.

Answer (score -1):

Just replace all "--" Occurence, and you should get only "-" after that

Comment: what about whitespace?

Comment: And what about "----" ?

Comment: @Codeartist repetition will finds strings longer than `--`. But this should be explained in the answer

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried str_replace("---","-",$string)?. This way if there are three minus in sequence, they will be replaced by only one.

Comment: One without whitespace around it.